# How do I use a custom PMD rule in SonarQube 5.5?

Tags: sonarqube, customization, pmd

I have a ruleset.xml file with custom PMD rules. How do I use this file in SonarQube 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this topic (and answer): [SonarQube how to create Profile and import new rules to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057835/sonarqube-how-to-create-profile-and-import-new-rules-to-it)

You can import the rules simply by using the class RulesDefinitionXmlLoader with the method load like this:

```
RulesDefinitionXmlLoader.load(repository, new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(ruleset.xml)));
```

Hope it helps to get you going.

Comment: Does ruleset.xml contain PMD rules in format: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/howtomakearuleset.html ?

Comment: Yes. Or more simply like tihs: http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/4.3/apidocs/org/sonar/api/server/rule/RulesDefinitionXmlLoader.html
The top elements are mandatory.

Comment: You can view more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011846/sonarqube-does-not-show-imported-rules-in-quality-profile).